# update then select value which updated by other transaction but get the value before update

Tags: mysql, transaction-isolation, repeatable-read

mysql: 8.0.23

transaction isolation level: repeatable read

test data:

```
create table test.test (
    id int primary key,
    value int
);

insert into test.test(id,value) values(1,0);
```

In same transaction, we get output value is 1 as we have execute update set value = 1.

```
start transaction;

select value from test.test where id = 1; -- output: value is 0

update test.test set value = 1 where id = 1;

select value from test.test where id = 1; -- output: value is 1

commit;
```

Whereas in different transaction, things become strange:

|  | A Transaction | B Transaction |
| --- | --- | --- |
| t1 | `start transaction;` |  |
| t2 | `select value from test.test where id = 1; -- output: value is 0` |  |
| t3 |  | `start transaction;` |
| t4 |  | `select value from test.test where id = 1; -- output: value is 0` |
| t5 |  | `update test.test set value = 1 where id = 1;` |
| t6 |  | `select value from test.test where id = 1; -- output: value is 1` |
| t7 |  | `commit;` |
| t8 | `select value from test.test where id = 1; -- output: value is 0` |  |
| t9 | `update test.test set value = 1 where id = 1; -- 0 row affected` |  |
| t10 | `select value from test.test where id = 1; -- output: value is 0 (**so wired**)` |  |

so what happen at t10, why the value output is 0 ?

Answer (score 1):

Update statement of transaction A doesn't take effect at t9, because the value has been updated to a same value by transaction B. So t9 return "0 row affected" which means it's the other transaction (B) which modified the value rather then A transaction it self. So the select statement at t10 get the value in read view that is value 0.